# Create a sloppy Ubuntu package for Travis CI

Tags: packaging

I develop on software A which depends on software B and C, software B depends on D, which ships a convenience copy of C as well. For my work on A and B, I'd like to have continuous integration with GitHub. That can be provided by Travis CI easily.

My issue with Travis CI is that it runs on Ubuntu Trusty. My workstation runs Fedora, the supercomputer that I deploy to runs CentOS 7. The C/C++ code compiles on all platforms, this diversity just means much more work.

Building a single library on Travis CI is not a problem, I can do that. Currently I build all those dependencies when I build A, which is a waste of resources and time. The “proper” solution would be having Ubuntu Trusty packages of the dependent libraries at some release version.'

While building these packages I found that Debian packages are much more cumbersome than RPM packages. In the RPM package, I just do the following:

```
%build

aclocal
autoreconf -f
./configure \
        --disable-testing \
        --enable-clover \
        --enable-mm-malloc \
        --enable-openmp \
        --enable-parallel-arch=scalar \
        --enable-proc=AVX \
        --enable-soalen=4 \
        --libdir=%{_libdir} \
        --prefix=/usr/ \
        CXX=/usr/bin/g++ CC=/usr/bin/gcc  \
        CXXFLAGS="-O2 -finline-limit=50000 -Wall -Wpedantic -fmax-errors=1 -fopenmp --std=c++11 -Drestrict=__restrict__" \
        || cat config.log

make %{?_smp_mflags}

%install
%make_install
```

Then it will do all these steps. With Debian, that is probably possible by just overriding `build:` in the `debian/rules` file. However, it still tries to run `dh_auto_clean` which will then find the in-tree build artifacts (obviously …). I cannot run `make clean` before calling `autoreconf`, though.

This means that I cannot run `debuild -S`, which means that I cannot build it on a Launchpad PPA, which means that I cannot install that package on Travis CI.

What is a sensible way to get a simple, sloppy Ubuntu package from my GNU Autotools projects (often nested subprojects)?

Comment: I believe that I had faced such  `autoreconf`/ `dh_auto_clean` issue before in Debian packaging, Could you add the contents  of `debian/rules`?